# Required checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a small form. In this form if either *item a* or *item b* are selected a third checkbox should be ticked. This checkbox is disabled the user should not be able to thick it on its own. Once *item a* or *item b* are unchecked the third required items should stay checked, however if both items are unchecked the required item should be unchecked aswell.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" value="50.00" class="itema" />Item a</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" value="40.00" class="itemb" />Item b</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="item2" disabled />Required by item a and b</p>
```

Using the code below I got it working for the checking, but I no clue how to get the conditional unchecking done

```
$(function () {
    $('.itema').change(function () {
        $('.item2').prop('checked', true);
    })
    $('.itemb').change(function () {
        $('.item2').prop('checked', true);
    })
});
```

Here is a fiddle with some more code
http://jsfiddle.net/mthomas/ejQjP/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't solving the work 100% for you, but I think this is where you were having a problem, so I suggest you take it from here.

You want to check the state of the checkbox within the change function

```
$('.item1').change(function () {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked'); // will be true after checking and false when unchecking
    $('.item2').prop('checked', isChecked)
               .prop('disabled', isChecked)
               .change();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejQjP/17/

**edit** you probably want to trigger the change event on the newly checked checkbox

**PS:** There is no reason to have 3 document ready functions, every `$(document).ready(function () {` & `$(function () {` can be put into one.

Comment: This did part of the trick. I see you are using an older version of the fiddle (might be my mistake). But in a newer version there are two items a and b, that can trigger the check/uncheck of item2. And if item a or b is checked item 2 should be checked aswell, so if both of them are checked, and one is unchecked item 2 should stay checked only if both item a and b are unchecked item 2 should be unchecked

Comment: well then something like `var isChecked = $('.item1').is(':checked') || $('.item2').is(':checked');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('.itema , itemb').change(function () {
           var  isChecked = $('.item2').is(':checked');
           var  isChecked1 = $('.item1').is(':checked');

           if(isChecked == true && isChecked1 == true)
            $('.item2').prop('disabled', true);

           else
            $('.item2').prop('disabled', false);

    })

});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? How would you use this in the OP's code?